# Как взять только один раз айди фото

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Здраствуйте, как мне взять только один раз `file_id` фотографии из группы? мне нужно сделать массив из этих айдишок и занести в БД.

Я имею вот такой код:

```
import logging

from aiogram import Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import Message, ChatActions, MediaGroup

from setting import ADMIN_1

async def test_function(message: Message):
    try:

        print(message.photo)

    except Exception as err:
        logging.exception(err)

def register_message_handler_admin_test_function(dp: Dispatcher):

    dp.register_message_handler(
        test_function,
        lambda message: message.from_user.id == ADMIN_1,
        content_types = ['photo']
    )
```

Отправляю фотографии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате мне в консоль отправляется два сообщения.

```
{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAPLYji9F13-RkqXKVmENDXhLu0PO2IAArq5MRvCN8BJ1T-N-U-0crMBAAMCAAN5AAMjBA", "file_unique_id": "AQADurkxG8I3wEl-", "file_size": 40020, "width": 1000, "height": 519}
{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAPMYji9F9wuduCRm4XskNhpNWktIn0AAmy6MRs26cFJi1S0JkIfPokBAAMCAAN4AAMjBA", "file_unique_id": "AQADbLoxGzbpwUl9", "file_size": 10491, "width": 800, "height": 600}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У вас на руках массив с айограмовским типом данных PhotoSize, просто обратитесь по индексу, а потом по "file_id"
`message.photo[0].file_id`

Comment: не работает, ```'PhotoSize' object has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: Мой косяк, думал то словарь, а там свой айогрмовский тип. Обновил проверяй.